# If a capacitor plate is equipotential then how come it has different potentials on the inner and outer plate during the charging phase?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, voltage, capacitance, conductors

I have a very fundamental doubt:

Consider a capacitor with plates name $X$ and $Y$, Since the plates of capacitor happen to be conductors, they are going to have equal potential at all points. Now if we assume that the outer surface of plate $X$ is at a potential $V$, the inner plate of $X$ is also going to have the same potential $V$.

Further, if we assume the outer plate of $Y$ is at $0$ potential, the inner plate is also going to have $0$ potential, as the whole conductor is equipotential.

Now, isn't the potential difference between the inner plates going to be $V$ all the time (in the charging phase also)? 
And as a consequence, The charge on the inner plates cannot change, since $Q=CV$, and $C$ and $V$ both are constant during the charging phase. (According to my argument).

Please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Consider this situation]

Let us consider the initial instant of charging. The charge on both the capacitor plates is Zero. This is time **t=0**

As the current flows through the circuit, it reaches the plate X (**face A**). Now let us pause the time to understand what happens next.

The Charge at plate X is **q**(say). In order for plate Y to remain at Zero potential (because it is grounded) it shall extract an equal charge of **-q**. Now this reduces the situation to a [Gauss law](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/gaulaw.html) problem.

Clearly, the electrostatic field inside the conductor is always ***zero***. So, the charge must be distributed on the inner plates, i.e. B has charge 'q' and C has charge '-q'.

Therefore at each instant, there is gradual increase in potental of the capacitor, 
from 0 to $V_0$.

Also the potential of plate X is $V(t)$ throughout, this is because of the absence of electric field at any instant **inside** the conductor (plates), so the potential of the inner faces becomes the potential of the respective plate.

**P.S.** 1. The consideration that there is **no** electric field inside the conductors is 
             **purely** **for an instant**. We are considering the electrostatic 
              situatuion at any time.Needless to say we also assume the fact that charge 
              rearrangement takes place instantly so as to avoid uneccessary 
              complications.

```
     2. I am considering the classical model and do not delve into the Quantum world
        implications in any way.

     3.You may consider a resistance $R$ in the circuit applied in series to not make 
       current shoot upto infinity when the capacitor is charging.
```